# Como hacer para que no se repitan los numeros aleatoriamente en un rango con python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo en mente hacer una especie de juego tipo elecciones en donde los votos se generan aleatoriamente, el problema es que no logro que el random genere numeros aleatorios dentro de un rango, por ejemplo le digo a random que intercambie 1 y 2 aleatoriamente y lo que consigo es que en todo un rango de el mismo numero... les dejo un screen para ser claro...! [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3996930/4092887).

Comment: Por favor el código escribelo en el formato adecuado, no como imagen, para que sea más fácil copiarlo y reproducirlo.

Comment: Disculpame ese error, lo que pasa es que me gusta también poner el error gráficamente para que se tenga una mayor idea... en las próximas dudas que tenga colocaré el código también!

Comment: El error puedes mostrarlo gráficamente, pero el código que esta produciendo el error digitalo en el formato adecuado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estas generando el número aleatorio fuera del ciclo. Es decir, la función `randint` solo se ejecuta una vez generando un solo número aleatorio (que guardaste en la variable `valor`).

Para que te genere un numero aleatorio diferente, debes poner la función `randint` dentro del ciclo, por ejemplo:

```
import random
for a in range(11):
  valor = random.randint(1, 2) # fijate que esta dentro del ciclo
  print(a, valor)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! estoy empezando a programar con Python3 y no sabía lo de meter el randint dentro del ciclo!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
import random

for a in range(11):
    print(a, random.randint(1,2))
```

Comment: funciona también para lo que tengo en mente! gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Si el rango no es muy grande, puedes crear un array booleano, llamado por ejemplo "disponible", inicializado en true, que indicará que números del rango estan disponibles, y una variable "disponibles" con la cantidad de números aleatorios que tenemos disponibles, inicializado en disponible.length , entonces elegir un numero al azar entre 1 y "disponibles", y recorrer "disponible" buscando la posición "true" numero "azar", la posición será la respuesta, asignamos "false" en la posición "azar" y decrementamos "disponibles".
De esta manera, saltándose los disponible "false" solo saldrán una vez.
Disculpa que no muestre codigo python, pero no lo conozco.
Ejemplo en javascript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<button onclick="aleatorio()">Mostrar numero aleatorio</button>
<button onclick="resetear()">Resetear rango</button>

<SCRIPT>
var rango=11; // de 0 a 10;
var disponible=[];
var disponibles;

function resetear(){
 for (var i=0; i<rango; i++) disponible[i]=true;
 disponibles=rango;
}

function aleatorio(){
 if (!disponibles) {document.body.innerHTML+="Fin "; return;}
 var azar=Math.floor(Math.random()*disponibles)+1;
 var contador=0, posicion=0;
 while (contador<azar) if (disponible[posicion++]) contador++;
 disponible[--posicion]=false;
 disponibles--;
 document.body.innerHTML+=posicion+" ";
}
resetear();
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: La pregunta hace referencia a Python 3, tu respuesta está escrita en Javascript.

Comment: Si, lo se, lo pone en la propia respuesta.